# Removing characters from fetchall output- Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

How can I remove the following from the fetchall() output :

```
[('test',)]
```

The output I'm looking for:

```
'test'
```

I tried using x.strip() but its not working in this case and its raising this error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'**

Thanks for your help

**Code sample:**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

c = conn.cursor()
t1 = 'loop'

# Query table
c.execute('select col1 from table where symbol=?', t1 ')
            
x= c.fetchall()

conn.close()
```

Comment: Use `result[0][0]`

Comment: thanks but it didn't work

Comment: What was the error? Don't say `NameError: name 'result' is not defined`

Comment: x[0][0], the outcome didn't change, it still as it is.

Comment: It will not change if you don't assign it to something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nested version of replace

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace('[(''test'',)]', '[',''),']',''),'(',''),')',''),',','')
```

Looks ugly but it works.
The logic behind this:
replace('Your string','x','y')
where x is the digit you want to be replaced
and y the digit you want to put in its place.

Another logic is using the translate build in function

```
select translate('[(''test'',)]', '()[]{},', '       ');
```

translate('Your String','ab','cd')
Replaces a with c and b with d. So you can insert all the digits you don't want on the left and the blank spaces on the right.

Comment: Thanks but in this case i have to hard code the value x,y every time I got a different output from sql.